# why I receive some empty data received from the serialPort?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, buffer

I extracted the data from my sensor using these command lines:

```
QObject::connect(this->serialPort,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(pollSerialPort()));
QObject::connect(serialPort, &::QSerialPort::errorOccurred,this,&Imu::handleError);

QByteArray hexData = d.append(serialPort->readAll().toHex());

qDebug() << "Serial received " << hexData;
```

however, I do not receive the data every time

I have a lot of empty messages like this

Serial received "555541321e7ff3029f61da00000000ffff00d2fffa0cbe24b124b124b1007b13d00000f4d8"

Serial received ""

I used this command to receive the data every ms but it doesn't work

QObject::connect(this->serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, this {QTimer::singleShot(5,this,&Imu::pollSerialPort);});
Any solution please ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to find where the "Error, Uknown error". originates from in your program? If so, please trim down your program to the minimum code required for the error to occur.

Comment: yes, but it does not give me more details

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What the cause of "Error, Uknown error" is and how to fix it? How to read from a serial port in general? If it is the former, please reduce the code to the minimum necessary to produce the error for you so we can help you narrow it down. If it is the latter, there are plenty of Qt tutorials on that topic and I'd advise you to look at those.

Comment: Yes, my question is What the cause of "Error, Uknown error"

Comment: Please consider taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - this will make things easier for people trying to help you and simulataneously increase the chances that someone will be able to assist you.

Comment: I really would want to help you, but at this point I am not even certain from which point of your program the error message "Error, Uknown error" originates from (BTW: is it really "Error, Uknown error" or did you paraphrase and include a typo? The exact, original error message can be vital here)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling on a timer, connect QSerialPort::readyRead to a slot and inside the slot use QSerialPort::readAll() until  QSerialPort::bytesAvailable() is 0.

Comment: Thank you.   How to do this please. I used this command                                                   ''' QObject::connect(this->serialPort,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(pollSerialPort()))'' . But i haven't nothing . How to use so "Until QSerialPort::butesAvailable() is 0.